# State not preserved in component render() in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

In React Navite, I am saving an array of values from Firebase and rendering Views for each value. I cannot the values from inside the `render()` function. There is no exception on any trouble, the array is just empty from within `render()`. I don't think this is normal behaviour, can this be fixed?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import _ from 'lodash'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import SessionsList from './SessionsList';

export default class HomeScreenTest extends React.Component {
    state={
        categories:[],
      }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(configTest) : firebase.app();
  }

   async componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref("listings/ids").once("value", snapshot => {
        let values = snapshot.val();  
        let indexes = _.keys(values);  
        this.setState({categories:indexes});
        alert(this.state.categories);    //Works fine, categories populated with values
        });  
  }

  render() {
    let categories = this.state.categories.map(element => { // categories empty, no output 
        <View style={styles.category} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SessionsList')}> 
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            {element}
          </Text>
        </View>
    });
    return (
      <ScrollView>
          {categories}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything :)

```
 let categories = this.state.categories.map(element => { // categories empty, no output 

// SHOULD RETURN THIS DO IT LIKE THIS
        return (<View style={styles.category} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SessionsList')}> 
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            {element}
          </Text>
        </View>)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
 let categories = this.state.categories.map(element => { // categories empty, no output 
        <View style={styles.category} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SessionsList')}> 
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            {element}
          </Text>
        </View>
    });
```

to:

```
 let categories = this.state.categories.map(element => ( // categories empty, no output 
        <View style={styles.category} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SessionsList')}> 
          <Text style={styles.instructions}>
            {element}
          </Text>
        </View>
    ));
```

Comment: No, changing brackets didn't help. I see in the debugger that the problem is not with the syntax, but this.state.categories is an empty array in the render().